# IE6 memory leak while loading content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-6

I think that I have a memory leak in my app witch I can't localize.

The application downloads content and displays it. When the content is already downloaded it just displays it (because it was downloaded earlier).

The bug shows up when I choose at least 10 different options from the select.
(choose option 1 and confirm with #wcc-submit and wait to load, ..., choose option 10 and confirm with #wcc-submit and wait to load). With each selected option the app gets slower. Finally this error shows up:

[image: IE 6 error]

The app is tested in IE6.

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
$(function(){
var language = 'de';
var fadeOutSpinnerFadeInContent = function(pageID) {
    $('#wcc-loader').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('#wcc-content-'+pageID).fadeIn(500);
    });
};
var makeAjaxCall = function(pageID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/some/path/'+language+'/'+pageID+'.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',

        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#wcc-content-container').append('<div id="wcc-content-'+pageID+'" class="wcc-content hide">'+data+'<div>');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error');
        },
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            fadeOutSpinnerFadeInContent(pageID);
        }
    });
};
var downloadContent = function(pageID) {
    $('#wcc-loader').fadeIn(500, function() {
        makeAjaxCall(pageID);
    });//end fade out spinner
};
var openPage = function(pageID) {
    var earlierContent = $('.wcc-content');
    if( earlierContent.size() > 0 ) {
        earlierContent.fadeOut(500, function() {
            if( $('#wcc-content-'+pageID).size() > 0 ) {
                $('#wcc-content-'+pageID).fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                downloadContent(pageID);
            }
        });
    } else {
        downloadContent(pageID);
    }
};

var availableHashArray = [
    '-1',
    'page_id_1',
    'page_id_2',
    ...
    'page_id_100',
    ],
    choosenHash = $.inArray( window.location.hash.substring(1), availableHashArray);

$('#wcc-submit').bind('click.cs', function() {
    var selectedValue = $('#select-1').val();

    if(parseInt(selectedValue, 10) !== -1) {
        window.location.hash = selectedValue;
        openPage(selectedValue);
    }
});

if( choosenHash !== -1 ) {
    $('#select-1 option[selected="selected"]').removeAttr('selected');
    $('#select-1 option').eq(choosenHash).attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('#wcc-submit').trigger('click.cs');
}

});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="wcc-form" class="fm-form">
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <div class="select-form">
                    <label class="hidden" for="select-1">Choose an option</label>
                    <select id="select-1" class="fm-text fm-select" name="select-1" >
                        <option value="-1" selected="selected">Choose an option</option>
                        <option value="page_id_1" selected="selected">option 1</option>
                        <option value="page_id_2" selected="selected">option 2</option>
                        ...
                        <option value="page_id_100" selected="selected">option 100</option>
                    </select>
                    <input id="wcc-submit" type="button" value="Show" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="wcc-content-container">
</div>
<div id="wcc-content-container">
    <div id="wcc-loader" class="hide"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
<style type="text/css">
.hide{
    display:none;
}
#wcc-loader{
    height:50px;
    background:#fff url('/some/path/to/spinner.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
    #select-1{
        margin-left:20px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah yes, I know the answer to this one.

**"Disregard the whole problem because it's IE6 and it has to die."**

What? Someone had to say it.

Comment: I fully agree. But my boss has a different opinion.

Comment: @czerasz I understand man, I really hope someone knows the answer. I'll take a look.

Comment: I know, let's fix the problem by redefining the scope to "only works in the environment that it works in...". :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a JavaScript profiler like dynaTrace Ajax Edition (free) to find the slowest part of your script.

http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/

Answer (score -1):

It is most likely a jQuery problem that you don't really have control over. (Other than not using the part of the code that is producing the memory leak).

Back in those days, JS wasn't meant to do this sort of thing.

Comment: This is not a particularly useful answer. Would be better as a comment.